Two OS's on same partition
I installed two OS's, 18.04 and 20.04, on the same partition of my Hard drive.
Is it possible to move one OS to a different partition of the same hard drive?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services. This site can help with your 20.04 system, not the 18.04 which is off-topic now; SE Unix & Linux allows both

Yes it is possible to move partitions around, or make changes post-install. I'd do it from a live system (so drive/partition isn't being used whilst you make changes) then you just correct the boot system if required to allow for changes you've made (how a system boots can vary; eg. legacy/MBR or uEFI differ, but I'd likely try to boot normally anyway first; then reboot live & correct if it didn't boot as expected; I'd think thru consequences of changes made though before I test-booted)

It is not possible to have two OSes on the same partition at the same time. The last OS you install will overwrite the previous OS. You can install two OSes in two different partitions on the same drive. Install the app Gparted. Open Gparted, and take a screenshot of the Gparted app's window. Add this screenshot into your question using the "picture" icon above the edit question window.

Do you have two OS at different partitions of the same hard drive? Installing two OS on the same partition is not possible AFAIK

FYI:  I took your 'two OSes on the same partition' as unclear instructions; I have a system here with single disk & single partition & two OSes on it... but it is far from a normal install requiring me to specially setup the system (something I'd not like to repeat! with me booting the second OS by inserting external media so as to pass boot process to non-standard location the machine firmware cannot do) so your details are unclear.

Open a terminal, run in it: sudo inxi -F, sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL, copy the outputs, edit your post and paste them in it.
